# Change text value on click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I change the text value from 'close' to 'open' or vice versa when clicking my H4 element?

http://jsfiddle.net/8snk7ev6/

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

        //Expand or collapse this panel
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast', function(){
            var status = $(this).is(':hidden') ? 'close' : 'open';
            $(this).next('.accordion-status').html(status);
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your current DOM structure, the selector should be:

```
$(this).prev('h4').find('.accordion-status').html(status);
```

Because `this` refers to the `.accordion-content` div, and the `accordion-status` div you're looking for is actually *before* it. Also, it's wrapped with an `h4` element.

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8snk7ev6/5/)

Comment: @michaelmcgurk : Welcome to stackoverflow. In this QA site, when an answer is realized, we do not append "(SOLVED)" to the question title. Instead, we mark a correct answer by clicking on the checkbox to the upper-left of that answer. If you come up with the answer yourself, then post your own answer, give it some time, and if no one has a better answer (your discretion), you can accept your own after a 48-hour wait period.

Comment: @CerlinBoss "member for 5 months" - I feel like I should be welcoming you to SO ;-) Apologies, the real world got in the way as it can do sometimes. If you'll have a look through my previous questions, you'll see I always mark a correct answer and give thanks. I never append "(SOLVED)" to the question title. Take care : )

Comment: the point of that comment is to make sure that the guy who put the effort get the credits for it. also being a member for more than 3 years doesn't justify anything. if you are really into stackoverflow then you should have accepted the answer before anyone pointing it out. FYI I am glad that you accepted the answer which helped you. :)

Comment: I'm glad too :-)
Unfortunately, there was a limit of 9 minutes between that answer being posted & myself being able to accept it. In that time I was taken away from my computer on a personal errand and was unable to accept the answer until now. As you can see from my profile, I accept the vast majority of answers. This was a rare occasion where there was a delay : D

Answer (score 0):

check below code or go to updated fiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8snk7ev6/8/)

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    var OBJ = '';
    $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){
        OBJ = $(this);
        //Expand or collapse this panel
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast', function(){
            var status = $(this).is(':hidden') ? 'close' : 'open';
            OBJ.find('div.accordion-status').html(status);
        });

    });
});
```